# Spring MVC with hibernate - locking database table by transaction (perform more operations in one transaction).

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

In my application, users can modify data in some table. I would like to have system, to prevent modifying this table concurrently by two or more users. I would like to have some button on page, which could lock that table, and only user, which locked this table could change data. My idea is, that by this mentioned button should start new transaction on that table, and only this user could perfom update or insert on that table. This transaction should be somwhere stored for instance in some variable in service object, and during saving data this transaction should by finished. That means, that i would like to have some method in dao or service class, which will by able to create new (named) transaction and store it into variable. Next service method calls should use this transaction and on data saving, transaction will be closed. Is it possible to do it like i wrote in spring with hibernate?

Now, i am using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` as entity manager and `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` bean as transaction manager. For defining transactions i am using `@Transactional` anotation in service class.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate,we can use pessimistic locking strategy to acquire lock on resources during insert or update.

Comment: but is it possible to lock whole table, no just some rows (entities)?? Because, i thought that in hibernate is possible to lock something in db only by entity object.